# How to find out which changeset introduced the particular code (lines, block)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am looking for the easiest way to track back, how was a change introduced to the code.

Could TFS show me based on a code line a block tell me from which **changeset** is it coming from? Probably no, but what would be the best method to find out. Rather than looking in the history and comparing one-by-bone.

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "[Annotate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979.aspx)" by right clicking the file [from Source Control Explorer, Solution Explorer], it will tell the changeset that the line was most recent.